# a learned regression tree`s depth

Tags: regression

Is it possible that a learned regression tree`s depth be larger than the number of training observation N used to create the tree?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum depth of a regression/classification/space-partitioning tree is equal to the number of data points, if every leaf node contains at least one point (i.e. there are no 'empty' leaf nodes). Reaching this maximum depth requires that:

1. All data points are unique (there no duplicates).
2. We perform binary splits.
3. Each split creates a new leaf node containing a single point.
4. Splitting continues until every point is assigned to its own leaf node.

For example (with data points labeled 1,2,3,4):

```
  (1 2 3 4)
   ___|___
  |       |  
 (1)   (2 3 4)
        __|__
       |     |
      (2)  (3 4)
           __|__
          |     |
         (3)   (4)
```

As a side note, this structure would typically give poor performance.

Deeper trees are possible if we permit empty leaf nodes (containing no data points). Indeed, if the the input space is continuous (or otherwise infinite), then arbitrarily deep trees can be constructed. In this setting, the requirements above no longer apply.